# Asp.net model date testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

Say I have a model for a product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For this product I have a Dto:

```
public class ProductDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, In my controller, I have a method that "creates" new products and records the current time in the `Created` attribute:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(ProductDto dto)
{
    return Ok(new Product()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        Name = dto.Name
    });
}
```

Say I wanted to unit test this method to verify that a newly created product is assigned a `DateTime` object other than the default `{01-01-0001 00:00:00}` it gets from the prop snippet, how would I go about that? I would prefer that `Created`, in the model, is not nullable.

Comment: Try `Assert.AreNotEqual(1, product.Created.Year)` or `Assert.AreNotEqual(DateTime.MinValue, product.Created)`

Comment: Of course! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.